# Can earthquakes affect the atmosphere?

Tags: earthquakes, rainfall

Recently an earthquake of magnitude 6.9 shook the northeastern region of India, where I live. After the earthquake, the climate has changed dramatically resulting in excessive hail showers, thunderstorms and heavy rain, continuously for 11 days until now.

It is the time for the usual monsoon period, but the weather is quite unusual. Can an earthquake affect the weather; is this kind of behaviour a common after-effect?

Comment: Take a look at this q - http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4514/what-impact-on-climate-did-2011-earthquake-and-tsunami-have/4524#4524

Comment: ... and this. http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240424/37364

Comment: The wikipedia article "P-wave" says, seismic wave can pass through air.  "P-waves are a type of body wave, called seismic waves in seismology, that travel through a continuum and are the first waves from an earthquake to arrive at a seismograph. The continuum is made up of gases (as sound waves), liquids, or solids, including the Earth.". permanent link:  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=P-wave&oldid=731991615. But how that could cause any rainfall? It would be a mere co-incidence.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no relation of earthquakes with the weather. But in a book, "Earthquakes- mitigation by Tatsch" there are several precursors associated with ponding earthquakes. One is unusual weather. Some of these precursors are pre- and some post-earthquakes. Your cited earthquake may have some relation with it.

Comment: It's a 40 year old reference. Do you have any reference to modern research on the topic?

Comment: +1'd for this research effort